# Proving Subspace of General Linear Group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n*n}$ and consider the sets:
$$S_1=\{TA  \mid T \in Gl_n(\mathbb R)\}$$
$$S_2=\{TAT^{-1}  \mid T \in Gl_n(\mathbb R)\}$$
$$S_3=\{TA  \mid T \in Gl_n(\mathbb Q)\}$$
$$S_4=\{TAT^{-1}  \mid T \in Gl_n(\mathbb Q)\}$$
$$S_5=\{AT^{-1}  \mid T \in Gl_n(\mathbb R)\}$$

Note:

$Gl_n(\mathbb R)$ is the invertible matrix n x n in Real Number.

$Gl_n(\mathbb Q)$ is the invertible matrix n x n in Rational Number.

Which of these sets, if any, is actually a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n*n}$?

From my understanding is, I need to make sure that all $T,A \in \mathbb R^{n*n}$ and the closure property is hold.

However, from my naive understanding of linear algebra, the multiplication of $T$ and $A$ is in $\mathbb R^{n*n}$. In addition, the Real Number set is consist of Rational Number sets.
Therefore, I conclude that all $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4,S_5$ are the subspace of $\mathbb R^{n*n}$.

I feel my approach is very naive. I would like to get a hint how should I prove whether the sets is in the subspace or no.
Thanks,

Comment: **Hint :** Which of these sets contain the zero matrix?

Answer (score 2):

None of these sets are actually subspaces of $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$, unless $A$ is chosen to be the zero matrix.  Notably, any subspace must contain the zero-element, which in this case is the matrix whose entries are all zero.

It doesn't make sense to talk about the "subspaces of $GL$", since $GL$ fails to be a vector space.